# How do you filter out the alphabet and random strings in MySQL to find the Max number?

Tags: mysql

I can get the max value for numbers(integers), but can't use this with strings (of course):

```
SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(EQNUM), 0) + 1) as  EQNUM FROM equip
```

I have seen this used below, but everything has a consistent string setup.  I am dealing with model numbers and different name lengths randomly placed.

How would you use `CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field,'-',-1),UNSIGNED INTEGER)` with *replacing random strings* [a-z],"-", " ", and [A-Z], with an empty space (basically "")?  (then we would find our max number from that formula afterwards with the coalesce()).

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This didn't have a path to the answer....  just a debate over mcve.

Comment: Then let that be your path.